# Java Android DC Audio Out

Tags: java, android, audio, robotics

I want to put a controllable DC voltage out the audio jack of an android device. My current solution is to create a 1 second array containing the PCM info for the waveform to be output (a flatline in this case).

The problem is that every second, there's a glitch where the output momentarily drops to zero volts. I believe this is happening at the point were the audio resource instance is created.

You can see that the audio is handled in its own thread. I will be changing the generatedSnd array in another thread.

Is there a smoother way of doing this? I have a feeling streaming is the wa to go, but I can't get my head round it.

```
private class OutDACrunnable
    implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        while (! done) {

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate, AudioFormat. CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

        audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);

        if (audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()) { } // use this later

        audioTrack.play();

        // wait until playback is complete
        int x = 0;
        do {
            if (audioTrack == null) {
                x = numSamples;
            } else {
                x = audioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition(); 
            }
        } while (x < numSamples);

        if (audioTrack != null) audioTrack.release();

        }
    }

} // OutDACrunbable
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to play continuously, just have a thread with a loop which keeps writing moderately large buffers to the audioTrack.  If you suspect skipping, try sending an audible sine wave and listening to it (choose a frequency such that you get an integral number of periods in a buffer, so it will be glitch free if the buffering is properly handled).  You might also want to try recording from a pc with a program such as audacity.  By using an audible test frequency you can also distinguish software problems from the general concern about possible AC coupling of the audio output.

Comment: Yep. Just need a piece of Android Java for that. I suspect I need a streaming version of what I already have but, stone me, the Oracle manuals are hard going!!

Comment: IIRC, you just call write(...) in a loop with your new, updated data. It blocks as needed. Don't release until you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the tip from Bjorn about write blocking as required, I tweaked my code. So, basically, I throw 20ms of sample at it every 15ms. It discards once the buffer is full, so I made teh buffer 20ms as well. This way it stays up to date with my demands and no blips...

```
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate, AudioFormat. CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        audioTrack.play();

    private class OutDACrunnable
        implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            while (! done) {
                playTone();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((int) (750 * duration));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(MyTag, "OutDACrunnable: " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        }

    } // OutDACrunbable

    void playTone() {

    //      Log.d(MyTag, "playTone: start");

            audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);

            if (audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()) { } // use this later

    //      Log.d(MyTag, "playTone: done");

    } // playTone

    public static void genTone(double amp1, double amp2) {

//      Log.d(MyTag, "genTone: start");

        // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
        // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
        int idx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
            // scale to maximum amplitude
            // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte, first short is left ch
            short val = (short) ((amp1 * 32767));
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
            val = (short) ((amp2 * 32767));
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);

        }
//      Log.d(MyTag, "genTone: done");
    }
```

And I just call GenTone as and when I want, with the two DCs I want output...

Comment: Just one problem, now. When the user hits the back button, I call finish(); At this point, I get teh message that the app (unfortunately) has stopped.

Comment: You don't want to use sleep like this, as it may cause buffer underflow if your thread doesn't get scheduled again soon enough (sleep times are minimum, not maximum) - making an allowance for that is the whole reason you use non-tiny buffers to begin with.  Just rely on the blocking behavior - sitting in a blocking call isn't that different from sleeping anyway, in terms of CPU utilization.

Comment: That gives me a new headache, though. If the originator changes the desired output voltage, won't a larger buffer have to play out before the newly demanded signal gets output?

Comment: Yes, you should expect non-trivial audio output latency on many Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't output DC from the audio jack. The audio I/o is designed to pass changing signals, generally speaking above 20 Hz. If you try to output DC, you will get something more like a pulse, which is what it sounds like you are getting.

Comment: While that is a general concern (ie, it may work or not at the whim of a given device's hardware design), the interval mentioned here looks more like a software problem.

Comment: indeed, looking at the question and code again, I think you are right. Nevertheless, I think it is a design problem to consider.

Comment: It's definitely a portability problem, though it may be that most mobile headset amps are not AC coupled these days (there are also sometimes debug serial channels on the same wires - not sure if they go through the amp).  It could be a solvable problem though, perhaps by using an AC output and rectifying/filtering.  I'd be tempted to look at using a frequency-to-voltage converter and remove the 'volume' dependence.  Or even modulated signaling to a simple microcontroller.

Comment: @Bjorn From a hardware perspective, I was concerned that this would be the case: it doesn't make sense to output a DC on audio! However the audio out of my Galaxy Tab 2 seems to be able to hold a DC quite nicely into a 200ohm load (similar to a set of earphones). The "blip" I'm seeing is at 1Hz, which is the frequency I'd expect as I'm refreshing the handle to the device every second. If I increase the buffer size, I can hold the DC for an increasing amount of time. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: @Chris, yes, a frequency is another possibility. The output will go to the ADC of a microcontroller and it would make the micro code simpler if I could just do a DC (which I'm happy I can with my chosen device). Many thanks.

Comment: Signaling by static analog voltage seems like a scheme likely to require quite a bit of device-specific-tuning, but have fun.  (Pulse timing could have a lot more immunity, while not requiring much of any signal processing sophistication)

Comment: See, I'm still tempted by what you're saying right there. If I used a pulse train, the receiver wouldn't care so much about the sender device output voltage. I feel a calibration exercise coming on!